# Is there any way to prevent duplicate subscriptions to same channel in Spring web socket

Tags: spring, websocket

I'm implementing a version of the stock application and noticed that user can subscribe same channel more then once. In those cases i see in web socket frames that message is duplicated to same user, with sub0, sub1... prefixes.

Unfortunately i didn't find how it possible to manage user subscription on server side and prevent duplicates.

Appreciate any help in this.

Comment: using  request.remoteAddress and sessionid ignore more than onces